# String contains the replaced value after using replace (Regex.lastMatch)

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, replace, gulp

I'm using gulp to generate HTML pages from tempaltes.

The templates look like this:

```
...
<script type="application/javascript">
{placeholder}
</script>
...
```

I am trying to replace the placeholder with some **minified JS code**.

My gulp build uses a method that looks like this:

```
function renderTemplate(minifiedJS) {
  var template = fs.readFileSync('template.html', 'utf-8');
  return template.replace('{placeholder}', minifiedJS); // this is ok because the {placeholder} appears only once.
}
```

However, the result looks something like this:

```
...
<script type="application/javascript">
 MINIFIED JS CODE{placeholder}SOME MORE MINIFIED JS CODE
</script>
...
```

How can it be that the replace worked, and the {placeholder} still appears in the *middle* of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of debugging, I found that the minified code contained the characters "$&".

This combination triggered a Regex feature called [RegExp.lastMatch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastMatch).

It replaced the {placeholder} with the minified JS code, and then it replaced the "$&" with the value "{placeholder}".

Yep.

I ended up changing the implementation to

```
function renderTemplate(minifiedJS) {
  var template = fs.readFileSync('template.html', 'utf-8');
  var splitTemplate = template.split('{placeholder}'); 
  return splitTemplate[0] + minifiedJS + splitTemplate[1]; // this is ok because the placeholder appears exactly once.
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing quote on line 3